# Performance counter to show real IIS response time

Tags: iis, performance, perfmon, performance-counters, response-time

What performance counter should I use to display current average IIS response time? ASP.NET counters correctly show the time spent in ASP.NET, but real latency is much bigger, which is confirmed by IIS logs and ab tool.

In more detail, ASP.NET Execution Time is significantly less then actual latency, ASP.NET Wait Time is zero, Web Service\Current Connections is equal to actual amount of requests issued to the server, Get Requests/sec is much slower (capped by 6, it seems).

I would like to see a total time IIS spent serving the request, is it possible using perfmon?